# What is the gender of $K(\pi,n)$ in French?

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, terminology, mathematical-french

This is a kind of silly question, but I don't know where else to ask.  Suppose I wanted to say "Ceci n'est pas une pipe" but with $K(\pi,n)$ substituted for "pipe." Would the article be "un" or "une"?

In case there are additional complications in the translation: What would be the French for "This is not a $K(\pi,n)$," where "this" refers to a picture over/under/beside the text?

Comment: What is $K(\pi,n)$ ?

Comment: Maybe it is better to say "Ceci n'est pas un espace $K(\pi,n).$

Comment: @Phira: an Eilenberg-Maclane space.

Comment: But maybe "un $K(\pi,n)$" works, suppressing "espace", which would be understood.

Comment: You should check Serre's foundational paper on the homotopy groups of spheres!  (I'd imagine it's in French?)

Answer (score 5):

You would use the same gender that the object's name has. For example, one could say:

Ceci n'est pas un $\triangle$ beside the picture of a square, but one could say

"Voici la $\mathscr{L}(cos(t))$" besides the expression of $\cos(t)'s$ Laplace transform.

Comment: So if I wanted to say "this is not a $K(\mathbb Z,1)$" beside a picture of a circle (which is, incidentally, a $K(\mathbb Z,1)$), would I use the gender for espace, cercle, or the letter K? (I guess in this case they are all the same, but I'd like to know how this works.)

Comment: Well, you'd be correct since it's just a *picture* of a $K(\mathbb{Z},1)$.

Comment: From your comment underneath your question, you say $K(Z,1)$ is a Maclane space, so in french, Un espace de Maclane. You would say Ceci n'est pas un $K(Z,1)$

Answer (score 4):

*Espace* and *K* both take "un".$\quad$